# wordpress get_categories returning empty array when used with 'parent' or 'child_of' parameters

Tags: wordpress

I am experiencing some weird behaviour from WordPress when I use the `get_categories` function. When I use the below, it gives me a blank array.

`get_categories(array('child_of' => 47, 'taxonomy'=>'category', 'hide_empty'=>0));`

But if I remove the `child_of`, it works fine. If I replace `child_of` with `parent`, it also gives me a blank array.

What's even weirder is when I did a `var_dump` on `get_categories`, it gives me an array with no `parent` or `category_parent` (see the image below). I compared it against the `wp_term_taxonomy` and the table appears to be okay.

[Screenshot comparing MySQL table and var_dump()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV96h.jpg)

Any ideas on what might be causing this? Have I overlooked something? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any posts in the category?

Comment: @HowardE - hey! They have specified 'hide_empty' => 0, so it shouldn't matter. My question is - is this the correct DB? The relation shouldn't look like this. I see it's on WPEngine. Maybe there's object caching enabled?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/#comment-3081

Comment: @HowardE - Thank you for the suggestions. I've found the culprit... PublishPress Permissions plugin. Once I turn it off, everything becomes normal.

Comment: Did you try bulk add, or used admin panel?